# Copy a small 2d array into a larger 2d array that has a buffer to the left and top

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I want to place the contents of a 2d array of ints into a larger 2d array of ints which has a buffer of 1 column to the left and 2 rows at the top. The width and height of both arrays can vary, but the content will always be large enough to exactly fit the larger array.

larger array: (9 is just a filler value)

```
9 9 9 9 9 9 9

9 9 9 9 9 9 9

9 0 0 0 0 0 0

9 0 0 0 0 0 0

9 0 0 0 0 0 0

9 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

content to copy: (will be full of random numbers)

```
3 1 2 3 3 5

6 7 5 5 6 5

2 1 3 5 2 2

1 3 5 2 2 5
```

expected output:

```
9 9 9 9 9 9 9

9 9 9 9 9 9 9

9 3 1 2 3 3 5

9 6 7 5 5 6 5

9 2 1 3 5 2 2

9 1 3 5 2 2 5
```

Comment: Maybe flatten the `content to copy` array, then loop `larger array` and substitute all `0` in the latter with sequential values from the former.

Comment: If that’s for Windows, use [DllImport] to call MFCopyImage from mfplat.dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcopyimage

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that the content array will have different values every time it is instantiated so I can't rely on a loop to substitute all values.

Comment: For your example, if the arrays have 1 byte per pixel, you need to pass pDest = address of the pinned array + 15, lDestStride = 7, pSrc = address of the pinned source array, lSrcStride = 6, dwWidthInBytes=6, dwLines=5. Don’t forget to specify GCHandleType.Pinned when pinning both arrays, or if you have unsafe code enabled use it, it’s slightly faster than `GCHandle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
int[,] contentToCopy = { //5x6
    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

int[,] arr = new int[7, 7];

for (int x = 0; x < contentToCopy.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < contentToCopy.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        arr[x + 2, y + 1] = contentToCopy[x, y];
    }
}
```